# How to set the default schema in DBeaver?

Tags: database, dbeaver

I am having trouble with the DBeaver default schema. When I set the default schema and close DBeaver, on next startup Active catalog/schema is N/A. How to fix this?

Comment: Looking for answers about databases, not related to programming? Look at the stack exchange site about databases: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<your db connection> => Edit connection => Connection settings => Initialization => Default schema

[image]

Comment: @MirkoDjuric If it works, you might consider marking the answer as accepted and upvoting it. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work for Oracle in DBeaver 22.3.3 https://pasteboard.co/FI3uiaNDuBSH.png

Comment: Thanks! The right click in the navigation pane and click `set default` is a real foot-gun that just confuses everyone into wondering why it doesn't work.